# Raw SQL SELECT in EF Core 3.1 on dynamic Table

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

My trivial problem is this: I need to select a single field from a table filtering by the Id field.

Something that in SQL I would simply write like this:

```
SELECT Field FROM {Table} WHERE Id = 1
```

The table name is variable.

How do I do this very trivial Query with EF Core 3.1 considering that the table name can vary?

I have already tried

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"SELECT TOP 1 Field FROM {table} WHERE Id={id}")
```

but I cannot read the result (it always returns -1)

I also tried this:

```
var test  = context.Set<T>()
    .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT Id FROM {table}")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

but give me an error because it wants all the fields in the select statement

Thanks for the support